# How many unique Mystery Boxes are there?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

I am trying to farm Star Coins to unlock the Special World levels, and I noticed that sometimes, I get Mystery Boxes that I have already seen. I cannot get another Star Coin from them (the Star Coin in the box is transparent, and if I collect it, I get 3 regular coins instead).

How many unique Mystery Boxes are there? I am assuming there is a finite number, otherwise I would get a new Star Coin every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are apparently [35 distinct mystery box rooms](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/620831-super-mario-3d-land/answers?qid=302094)**, 20 regular mystery boxes with 1 coin each and 15 gold mystery boxes with 2 coins each for a total of 50 star coins from mystery boxes. More than the single-player maximum star coins of 335 can be earned through StreetPass mystery boxes which are duplicates of those 35 rooms. To see all variations, you need to reset the mystery boxes by either waiting 24 hours or changing the date/time on your 3DS.